# Feathering Edges in Node compositor

Tags: node-editor

Is there a simple way to feather edges in the Node compositor?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a vignette to a render is fairly common and you can find examples in many tutorials. A vignette is often circular and darkens the corners but the same principal applies.

Basically you create a mask, blur it, then use it to mix together the results you want. In this example I have used a CombineRGBA to input a semi-transparent white background that I added a render result over. There is also an Ellipse Mask if you want the rounded result.

[image]

Comment: This method even works on abstract shaped masks, which is great.

Answer (score 4):

It is rectangular vignette effect. Easily achievable in blender compositor.

You need one Image with black and white colors. 
[image: Black & White Color]

In compositor. 
Insert your render layer to **Scale** Node.
Add your black and white image. 
Insert image to **Invert** Node. 
Add Color **Mix** Node. Set it to **Multiply**. 
Join Nodes from **Scale** & **Invert** to **Multiply** Node.
Add **Blur** Node and Insert Output of Multiply to Blur.
Add another color **Mix** node, set it to **Subtrac**t , Attach output of **blur & Scale** node to inputs and Join the output to **viewer & composite** Node.
[image: Vignette Effect]
Play with Settings for desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want full control over the effect in Blender and want it to scale to any image size and aspect ratio quickly, you can create the feather mask basis inside the Compositor, too:

*(Right click and open image in new tab for full size)*

[image: Compete Node-Setup]

For that, only take the original image (to get the dimensions of your image), make it white (see first **Mix-Node to white**) crop it with a black border (**Crop-Node**, **invert** and **Alpha over white**) and then **blur** the result to then use it as an Alpha channel or as a Mix node factor towards a white background.

A **Gamma-Node** after the blur can get you some fine-tuning control over the gradient of the feathering effect.

Comment: Sambler's method seems to be more straightforward, I didn't know a Box Mask node existed. Then this is more of a dirty workaround.

Comment: JulianHzg - your using the crop node is also useful, you don't need to feed the layer into it though, it appears to default to render size. I think the mask nodes came in during mango with the camera tracking.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. I'm just using to composit in a different file than the one I use for rendering, which is why I never have the correct rendering size set. Here, of course, that would be much easier.

Comment: I tried it without feeding it in there and I can't get it to work properly then. It seems to me that the size is only defined then the moment it is mixed with an image, so the crop node doesn't know which size to use.

Might be my mistake somewhere, though, but this exact setup doesn't work then.